# Existence of a special continuous function

Tags: continuity, analytic-continuation

I have stuck at a problem. " does there exist any continuous function that takes every real value exactly twice?"

Intuitively, I think such function cannot exist, as $x^2$, $|x|$, although they take every possitive value exactly twice, but they take $0$ only once. I tried to apply LMVT, but cannot make a concrete logic. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You're right that no such function exists. If $f$ were one then there would be two values $a < b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=1$. Then on the closed interval $[a,b]$ the function $f$ would have a maximum value $M$. We can assume $M > 1$ (if not, then use the minimum value).

If the maximum value $M$ appeared twice, at $c < d$   then find an $x$ near $c$ such that $1 < f(x) < M$. (You can do that using continuity). Then by the intermediate value theorem, $f$ takes on the value $f(x)$ between $a$ and $c$ and between $c$ and $b$. That's three times.

Comment: Why would the maximum value be achieved only once?

Comment: I think this takes a little fleshing out.  On $(a,b)$ we must have $f \gt 1$ or $f \lt 1$ because otherwise there would be a third point where $f(x)=1$.  WOLOG assume $f(x) \gt 1$ on $(a,b)$.  Then the maximum $c$ is achieved.  If there were two points where $f(x)=c$ either $f(x)=c$ for the whole range between them or it drops below $c$.  In that case there are four points where $f(x)=c-\epsilon$

Comment: See my edit, or @RossMillikan 's comment.